# How this query should be indexed to increase performance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I have a MongoDB query

```
Schema: Demo
{
  a: String,
  b: Number,
  c: Bool,
  d: Number
}

Query:
db.Demo.find({ a:'test', c: true }).sort({b:-1, d: -1}).limit(40).explain("executionStats")
```

I have tried applying these index:

**TYPE 1 INDEX**

1. db.Demo.createIndex({b-1, d:-1})
2. db.Demo.createIndex({a:1})
3. db.Demo.createIndex({c:1})

**TYPE 2 INDEX**

4. db.Demo.createIndex({a:1, c:1, b:-1, d:-1})

MongoDB always ignore `TYPE 2 index` as **rejected plans** and use `TYPE 1 Index`. But TYPE One is taking more time and I think it can be more optimized.

Explain Results by TYPE 1 QUERY.

```
....
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 20,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 351,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 647,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 647,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Perfect Index for the Query:

This has been explained in this blog

[Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/)

Query will be
`db.Demo.createIndex({c:1, b:-1, d:-1, a:1})`

Comment: because c is bool type and its cardinality is pretty low, I assume you don't need to include c in your compound indexes.